# Set Specefic Branch When Job Build periodically In Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-git-plugin, jenkins-tfs-plugin

My git Repository is Azure Dev-ops and I use Jenkins for Continuous Integration Build and I Use TFS Plugin for Jenkins.

I Use Pipeline for Build my project on Jenkins. I Want Jenkins can build my develop branch on midnight so i set Build Build periodically to `@midnight` but Jenkins Build the last branch was built. I want Jenkins to Build develop branch.
Is There any Way that I can set Branch in Build periodically?

Answer (score 0):

You can set wit build periodicaly with crontab, link for make crontab --> https://crontab.guru/

Comment: How can i use it with Jenkins??is it a Jenkins Plugin?